# get image from URL using XML parsing

Tags: android

I want edit image from url using xml parsing and that image display in gridview and more image display from device image gallery.how to get image please tell solutions for that

Answer (score 1):

```
private byte[] getImageByteArray(String url) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
            if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    return EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;

    }
```